# What kind of analysis should I run with more than one dependent numerical variables and more than one independent categorical variables?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a dataset like below. I have 2 dependednt variables `points` and `price` which are numerical and the rest of my independent variables are categorical.

```
 A tibble: 6 x 5
  country  points price taster_name        variety           
  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <fct>              <fct>             
1 None       88.4  3.59 None               None              
2 Portugal   87    2.77 Roger Voss         Portuguese Red    
3 US         87    2.71 Paul Gregutt       Pinot Gris        
4 US         87    2.64 Alexander Peartree Riesling          
5 US         87    4.19 Paul Gregutt       Pinot Noir        
6 Spain      87    2.77 Michael Schachner  Tempranillo-Merlot
```

I would like to know what kind on analysis would be the most proper for me to run in order to decide which of my independent variables are really independent of course and how much they affect each one of my  my dependent variables. I have already used random forest to predict prices based on the categorical variables I have.